# Links do not centre as required

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm having trouble aligning "buttons" in my pages, which are actually just text links that are made to look like buttons using CSS. It is used within an unordered list (see HTML below).

The responsible CSS code is here:

```
ul.cms {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0px auto !important;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.cms li {
    width: 24.99%;
    float: left;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px ;
    text-align: center;
    color: #666
}

ul.cms .has-icon {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 140px;
    margin: 0px 8px;
}

a.ja-typo-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: none;
    color: #333;
    background: none;
    text-align: center;

}

a.ja-typo-btn:hover,
a.ja-typo-btn:active,
a.ja-typo-btn:focus {
    border: none;
    background-position: bottom;
    color: #333;
}

a.ja-typo-btn-big {
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    font-size: 110%;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}

a.ja-typo-btn-big span {
    padding: 15px 23px;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

a.btn-green { background-color: #74af57 !important; border: none; }
a.btn-green:hover,
a.btn-green:active,
a.btn-green:focus { border-color: #74af57;  color: #fff; }

a.btn-green span { border: none; }
```

With the following HTML Code (I've cut out unnecessary text information as seen in the image below) :

```
<ul class="cms clearfix">   
    <li>
        <a class = "has-icon icon1" 
          href = "barista-course-melbourne/espresso-basics" 
          target = "_parent"></a>    
        <a class = "ja-typo-btn btn-green ja-typo-btn-big btn-big-green" 
          href="barista-course-melbourne/espresso-basics" 
          target="_parent"
          style="text-align: center; display: inline-block;">
            <span>COURSE INFO</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And renders in a mobile device like this where the button is not centred.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Any insight and help will be much appreciated.

This is the full HTML code I've used:

```
<div style="display: block;">
    <p> </p>
    <ul class="cms clearfix">
        <li>
            <a class="has-icon icon1" href="barista-course-melbourne/espresso-basics" target="_parent">
            </a>
            <h4>LEVEL 1</h4>
            <h4>Espresso Basics</h4>
            <br />
            <h4>3 hours - $99</h4>
            <span>An introductory barista course where you will learn fundamental barista skills.</span> 
            <a class="ja-typo-btn btn-green ja-typo-btn-big btn-big-green" href="barista-course-melbourne/espresso-basics" target="_parent">
                <span>    COURSE INFO    </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="has-icon icon2" href="barista-course-melbourne/latte-art" target="_parent">
            </a>
            <h4>LEVEL 2</h4>
            <h4>Latte Art</h4>
            <br />
            <h4>2 hours - $150</h4>
            <span>Learn to pour like a pro. You will learn to pour rosettas, hearts and tulips. </span>
            <a class="ja-typo-btn btn-green ja-typo-btn-big btn-big-green" href="barista-course-melbourne/latte-art" target="_parent" style="text-align: center;">  
                <span>    COURSE INFO    </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="has-icon icon3" href="barista-course-melbourne/advanced-barista-training" target="_parent">
            </a>
            <h4>LEVEL 3</h4>
            <h4>Advanced Barista</h4>
            <br />
            <h4>3 hours - $250</h4>
            <span>Do you have what it takes to become a top barista? Take your career to the next level! <br />
            </span>
            <a class="ja-typo-btn btn-green ja-typo-btn-big btn-big-green" href="barista-course-melbourne/advanced-barista-training" target="_parent" style="text-align: center;">
                <span>    COURSE INFO    </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="has-icon icon4" href="barista-course-melbourne/home-barista-training" target="_parent"></a>
            <h4>HOME</h4>
            <h4>Barista Classes</h4>
            <br />
            <h4>Various Classes</h4>
            <span>Take a range of our home barista classes in the comfort of your own home.<br /></span>
            <a class="ja-typo-btn btn-blue ja-typo-btn-big btn-big-blue" href="barista-course-melbourne/home-barista-training" target="_parent" style="text-align: center;">            
                <span>   LEARN MORE   </span>
            </a>
        </li>
</ul>
<div class="button-avartar clearfix">
    <p> </p>
    <p style="text-align: center;"> {modal href="barista-course-melbourne/index.php?tmpl=component&amp;id=2333" class="ja-typo-btn btn-red ja-typo-btn-big btn-big-red"}        
        <span>Upcoming Barista Course Dates</span>
        {/modal}
    </p>
<p> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to try using `margin: 0 auto;` instead of `margin: auto;`, the former will center it horizontally.

Comment: Let me know if that works for you. If not, maybe give me a link to the site or a jsfiddle and I'll try some stuff out.

Comment: I've tried margin auto doesn't seem to work

Comment: `margin: 0 auto;` not `margin: auto;`, they are two very different things.

Comment: Margin 0 auto won't work as it's an inline element

Comment: without a width you can't use margin auto, better off setting the width to like 90% or something.

Comment: In ul.cms .has-icon class you use margin property twice it may affect to css

Comment: Hi amol, I'll check that out when I get home. It may well be screwing it up.

Comment: So I removed the extra margin property and it has made no difference

Comment: I dont know if that will helps you, but after each span, make a div and give them the style **clear: both;** test it :)

Answer (score 0):

On the `li`, with the button, set `text-align:center` and `float:none`.

Comment: Hi Ray, if I set float to none it will cause my black icons to not render correctly. Currently .has-icon is set to float: left I think. I'm not home and on my ipad at the moment so can't check.

Answer (score 0):

Take out from `ul.cms li` the `width: 24.99%;` and `float: left;`

Comment: Hi Barnee, this does not work and causes the black circle icons to render underneath each other on a desktop or landscape in tablets

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the problem comes from, text-align:center on the li should center all inline-block elements inside. Could you show the full HTML structure? Maybe there is something between has-icon and ja-typo-btn?

Comment: @Lucas Lim adding width: 100% will make his float: left useless. If take out width: 100% in your jsfiddle example and re-size the output window so the width: 24.99% li will be bigger than the green link you-ll see that the link is centered.

Comment: Just copy/pasted your code into a fiddle and it works fine. I think the problem comes from the mobile device browser's interpretation. http://jsfiddle.net/e945S/ If possible add a <div class="clearAll"></div> above the ja-typo-btn link. Style .clearAll { clear: both; height: 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; overflow: hidden; }

Comment: Thank you. I solved the issue by surrounding each link with a `<div style="display: inline-block;"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of li to 100%. I did it inline, but you can do it in the external css itself.

```
<ul class="cms clearfix">   
    <li style="width: 100%">
        <a class = "has-icon icon1" 
          href = "barista-course-melbourne/espresso-basics" 
          target = "_parent"></a>    
        <a class = "ja-typo-btn btn-green ja-typo-btn-big btn-big-green" 
          href="barista-course-melbourne/espresso-basics" 
          target="_parent"
          style="text-align: center; display: inline-block;">
            <span>COURSE INFO</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nuxbox/LhDKb/

Answer (score 0):

On the `li` add position:relative and on the button use `position:absolute; top:0; left:50%;` that should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you are trying to apply margin twice:

```
ul.cms .has-icon {
    margin: auto; /* once here */
    display: block;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 140px;
    margin: 0px 8px; /* again here */
}
```

Try this:

```
ul.cms .has-icon {
    margin: 0 auto; /* center button, change 0 to 5-10 if you want some margin top and bottom */
    display: block;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 140px;
}
```